# How to track friends location?

Tags: java, android, gps, real-time

I am new in this field and I am trying to make application to track my friends like "snap-map". I am able to get my real-time location but I don't know what should I add to get real-time location of people who are using same application.

Here is my Java code, it will really helpful for me if you guys give me a code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
final static int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
final static String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};

private GoogleMap mMap;
MarkerOptions mo;
Marker marker;
private Location user;
LocationManager locationManager;
private HashMap<Float, Location> otherUser = new HashMap<Float, Location>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mo = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("My Current Location");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27 && !isPermissionGranted()) {
        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    } else requestLocation();
    if (!isLocationEnabled())
        showAlert(1);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    marker = mMap.addMarker(mo);
    }

//Called when the location has changed.
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    marker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myCoordinates));

}
//Called when the provider status changes.
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

//Called when the provider is enabled by the user.
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

//Called when the provider is disabled by the user. If requestLocationUpdates

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

private void requestLocation() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 10, this);
}

private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}

private boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v("mylog","Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }else{
        Log.v("mylog","Permission not granted");
        return false;

    }
}
private void showAlert(final int status) {
    String message, title, btnText;
    if (status == 1) {
        message = "Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                "use this app";
        title = "Enable Location";
        btnText = "Location Settings";
    } else {
        message = "Please allow this app to access location!";
        title = "Permission access";
        btnText = "Grant";
    }
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(btnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    if (status == 1) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    } else
                        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: You should use well maintained library https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib, because it takes much time to optimize location tracking code as battery drain.

Comment: You'll have to send the locations data to some server (like firebase), and then update the users with the new locations.

Comment: Means i have to create database into firebase?